# send email in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, events, listener

I want send activation link by email for users that registered. I use event and listener. I test my code step by step and don't any error and $code is exist. but in mailtrap no emails sent.

in mail/ActivitionUser I have this code:

```
public function build()
{

    return $this->subject('لینک فعالسازی')
    ->markdown('emails.active_user');
}
```

$code sent to struct funtion in mail file.

and in listener/SendMail :

```
 * @param  UserActivation  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(UserActivation $event)
{
    //send $user & $code to mail/ActivationUseAccount

   Mail::to($event->user)->send(new ActivationUserAccount($event->user,$event->activationCode));
}
```

Where can the problem be?